postman gets stuck on post request, jwtAuth, I added debugging console.logs to pinpoint error
postman post requests, gets to const user line, test3 logs on vs server terminal but not test4
=====================================================================================
vs terminal logs the following
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting node server.js
Server is starting on port 5000
test2
test3
=====================================================================================
postman request
http://localhost:5000/authentication/register
body, raw, json as follows.
{
    "email" : "pieter@gmail.com",
    "name" : "pieter",
    "password" : "kthl8822"
}

====================================================================================
postman data  pulls into vs fine no issues, validinfo middel ware runs clear,
email, name and password logs fine before crash.
=====================================================================================
the crash happens due to this line
const user = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = $1", [email]);
=====================================================================================
const router = require("express").Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const pool = require("../db");
const validInfo = require("../middleware/validInfo");
const jwtGenerator = require("../utils/jwtGenerator");
const authorize = require("../middleware/authorize");

//authorizeentication

router.post("/register", validInfo, async (req, res) => {
  const { email, name, password } = req.body;

  console.log("test2");
  try {
    console.log("test3");
    const user = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = $1", [email]);
    console.log("test4");

    if (user.rows.length > 0) {
      return res.status(401).json("User already exist!");
    }

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const bcryptPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    let newUser = await pool.query("INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_email, user_password)     VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *", [name, email, bcryptPassword]);

    const jwtToken = jwtGenerator(newUser.rows[0].user_id);

    return res.json({ jwtToken });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});

tried everything to catch the error but cannot, spend 2 days in combination with chatgpt going in circles, checked everything, it seems like the credentials in pool are wrong, and the app does not get access to postgres database, but the credentials in pool is the exact same as another app I am running without any hiccups, compared other app line for line in all files, nothing seems out of place or wrong, using postgres directly I tried pool credentials manually directly on postgres and it works fine.
i usually find these kind of bugs relatively quick but cannot see any fault this round

What query client are you using ?
